# Scponly: how can I block changing directories?

Tags: scp, ssh

I want to block users from changing directories when they log in via scponly's shell.  How can I do that?  I need to be able to provide users with their own upload directory that only they can see and read/write.  They should not be allowed to execute any code, ie, change directories or the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chrooted scponly might be what you're looking for.

if you use debian/ubuntu - when installing scponly you will be asked which version you want.

also read [here](http://sublimation.org/scponly/wiki/index.php/FAQ#Chroot_and_Debian).

Comment: +1 And you can run dpkg-reconfigure scponly if you're not running the chrooted version

Comment: The scoponly documentation says "if you don't know what chrooting is, don't do it."  I don't know what it is-- where's a good place to start looking?

Comment: @mmr - in essence making small environment - a jail - out of which process cannot go above [ you just make /some/dir/ to appear as root of filesystem for a process [eg scp server]]. dont worry - just follow the tutorial.